# Running Aptitude / apt-get resets archive lookup address

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, aptitude, resolv.conf

Having a problem updating ubuntu 12.04.02 lts box using aptitude - seems that the dns lookup value is getting changed somehow whenever I run aptitude or apt-get .

Example: a clean reboot:

```
me@server:~# ping us.archive.ubuntu.com
PING us.archive.ubuntu.com (91.189.91.14) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from orobas.canonical.com (91.189.91.14): icmp_req=1 ttl=49 time=49.4 ms
```

okay - resolving properly. Run aptitude:

```
me@server:~# aptitude update
Get:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise InRelease [4,254 B]                
Get:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-security InRelease [4,281 B]
Get:3 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates InRelease [4,278 B]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-security Release.gpg
 Got a single header line over 360 chars
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise Release.gpg
 Got a single header line over 360 chars
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates Release.gpg   
 Got a single header line over 360 chars
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-security Release      
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise Release                                                
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates Release       
100% [Connecting to guidetest.a.id.opendns.com (67.215.65.132)]
```

that's strange - not the proper IP address. Opendns is returning an error page. try ping again:

```
me@server:~# ping us.archive.ubuntu.com
PING us.archive.ubuntu.com (67.215.65.132) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from hit-nxdomain.opendns.com (67.215.65.132): icmp_req=1 ttl=52 time=16.5 ms
```

No proxy installed, opendns cachecheck shows the proper IP (91.189.91.14)

/etc/network/interfaces is

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
    address 10.1.2.250
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    network 10.1.2.0
    broadcast 10.1.2.255
    gateway 10.1.2.254
    dns-nameservers 208.67.222.222 208.67.220.220
```

/etc/resolv.conf is

```
 # Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
 # DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
 nameserver 208.67.222.222
 nameserver 208.67.220.220
 nameserver 10.1.2.254
```

(I've even commented out nameserver 10.1.2.254 in /etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/tail with no change)

I have another 12.04 box on the network using dhcp to 10.1.2.54 without any problems.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you able to use other name servers? OpenDNS's hijacking of NXDOMAIN responses can be very problematic, as you're seeing.

Comment: yes - I changed the NS settings to google (8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4) and updates work now.  Strange that the other box doesn't exhibit this NXDOMAIN problem.

Comment: @jimg It's using 10.1.2.54 though, correct?

Comment: yes - 10.1.2.254 does appear in resolv.conf - last nameserver entry.

Comment: @jimg I mean from your comment that "I have another 12.04 box on the network using dhcp to 10.1.2.54 without any problems." I interpreted that as it being the primary on the other system?

Comment: yes. The other 12.04 box is dhcp / using auto ethernet (dns 10.1.2.254) - tail has just 127.0.01 and a minimal network/interfaces (auto lo iface lo inet loopback). DHCP server provides opendns addresses.